# can't start slave on my apache spark standalone ec2 instance

Tags: ssh

This are the steps I've done so far:

1. Download spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
2. unzip
3. .spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh

Master is working but slave doesn't start

This is the output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-107 ~]$ sudo ./spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-ip-172-31-24-107.out
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-107 ~]$
```

This is the secure log

```
Aug  9 00:09:30 ip-172-31-24-107 sudo: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=./spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/start-all.sh
Aug  9 00:09:32 ip-172-31-24-107 sshd[4828]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

I believe the problem is with SSH but I haven't been able to find the solution on google...

Any idea how to fix my SSH issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed after running `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and restart the apache cluster afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try to run master by the following command:

```
start-master.sh -h IP_OF_MASTER"
```

and then run slaves. In my case it helped.